# Responsive table in css (properties in the rows instead of columns)

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a table, which I am trying to format properly for the responsive design. I have figured out how to do that in the case when the different items of the table are listed in the first column and their different properties are in the following columns.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    tbody td {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    tbody td:before {
        content: attr(data-th);
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

But I didn't figure out how to do it if I have a table, where different properties of the items are in different rows. For example, when there is a comparison of two products:

```
product a product b
100       200
5 years   7 years
```

and I would like it to be on a small screen like this:

```
product a
100
5 years
product b
200
7 years
```

What I have now is:

```
product a
product b
100
200
5 years
7 years
```

Any hints are very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php) to solve this issue.

You just need to set CSS something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
            display: block;
        }

        /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
        thead tr {
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

        td {
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%;
        }

        td:before {
            /* Now like a table header */
            position: absolute;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            top: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%;
            padding-right: 10px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
/*
        Label the data
        */
       td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "product a"; }
       td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "product b"; }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but somehow I get the same form as before, first property of the product a, below the same property of the product b, then the second property of the product a, and below the second property of the product b and so on. But I would like to have everything about the product a on the top pf the product b. Any ideas?